# Rewrite Mode and PHP using .htaccess not working (Error 404)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|ini|jpg|png|css|html|swf|flv|xml)$ index.php
```

I've been using this file for about a year now and frankly, if you ask me I'd say it means: If you're trying to access something **NOT** ended with js, ico, gif... flv, xml **THEN** redirect to index.php

Now I'm trying to deploy an application at a new server (centOS WITH mod_rewrite enabled) and I get the Error 404 when trying to access stuffs that usually works (at a different web server, for instance).

Since I know too little about it, I'd like some input on what should I be looking for to find the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should perform that kind of match in `RewriteCond`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|ico|gif|ini|jpg|png|css|html|swf|flv|xml)$
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Note: the first rule is needed so that the rules won't loop (exclude index.php itself from rewriting).

Comment: I'm led to believe that you are offering me a more elegant and better written code to do the same thing, which I appreciate. However, it did not change the status of my problem. In the server that my code works, your code works, in the server where I'm having trouble, it didn't change a thing.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu can you give a few examples of the URIs that don't work? By the way, when you hit 404, do you see the original url or rewritten one (as "non-existant")?

Comment: My problem was solved by changing AllowOverride from None to All. I didn't know I had to do that.

Comment: Sorry, i missed that bit ;) Should have told you. With `AllowOverride None` Apache does not read the `.htaccess` files at all.